# How do I get `bundle console` to not die to Ctrl + C

Tags: ruby, bundler

I'm going development on a ruby gem.  When I run `bundle console` it launches a ruby console that works like normal in all regards except that [Ctrl] + [C] kills the console.  In `pry` or `irb`, [Ctrl] + [C] just abandons the current input line and gives me a new one.  How can I get this behavior (killing the just entered line rather than the entire terminal session) through `bundle console`?

Update: this only happens with pry (which I have as a development dependency: `spec.add_development_dependency "pry", "~> 0.12.0"`).  When I comment out pry from the development dependencies and the console falls back to irb, [Ctrl] + [C] has the normal behavior of aborting the current input.  As I mentioned, running pry outside the context of `bundle console` also has the normal [Ctrl] + [C] behavior of aborting the current input; this problem only happens when running pry through `bundle console`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Maybe one of the gems registered a ctrl-c handler which kills the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `bundle exec pry` instead of `bundle console` fixes this.